# How to cache an HttpHandler based on session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching

I have a website that has a handler (implements `IHttpHandler`) that is used to generate dynamic stylesheets. It does this by getting an HTML colour code from session (based on the organisation a user is part of) and using some code (DotLess) to generate a stylesheet with that colour set in various places.

Given that the template is rarely going to change I figured that caching is in order but I of course need to make the cache dependent on the colour I get out of session.

Is there an easy built in way of doing output caching based on this value? I know I could do it based on querystring and various other things but not sure if it can be done on a session value like this. The other alternative of course is to create my own caching code but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 2):

You could make a cache key for output caching that involves the color as part of the key... "true" output caching is done at the kernel level ahead of the handler, and so it might be tricky to implement at the handler level a way to vary the key by the request.

Why not use a static, properly thread-safed (via locks) Dictionary... Where the key is the colour and the value is the CSS contents? The static object would live until app domain termination. You could use the static field member of the HttpHandler within the Handler itself to do caching. Busting said cache then becomes as simple as clearing or re-initializing the static field member reference.

Comment: Yeah, thinking about what you said about output caching happening before it hits the handler it makes sense that you couldn't do it from the handler itself. I can but hope though... :)

Comment: There are ways to do it in .NET 4.0 - implementing a custom output caching provider... but that's WAY overkill compared to a static dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely overkill but an interesting thought to consider for if I need it in the future.